# Add a file download link with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning everybody,

I'm using a website application which is named : **Dolibarr**. This application is scripted with `PHP` and owns a `MySQL` database in order to store data.

I have a page from Dolibarr which give me an array with some data : `id`, `name`, ...

[image]

I would like to get the possibility to download a .csv file which contain this data. I already scripted something but I get a download' window as soon as I gonna to this page :

```
    // mysql database connection details
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "*****";
    $password = "*****";
    $dbname = "dolibarr";

    // open connection to mysql database
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    // fetch mysql table rows
    $sql = "select * from llx_parts";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Selection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $fp = fopen('parts.csv', 'w');

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.replace('http://*********/parts/parts.csv');</script>";

    header("Location: http://********/parts/parts.csv");
    exit();

// End of page
llxFooter();
$db->close();
```

But I would like to create a download link just after my array instead of download window when I arrive on my page.

It's a friend project and I don't really have knowledges in PHP.